# UTF-8 Encoding Regex

Tags: regex

Hello I am bumping my head against the wall with Reg Expressions and UTF-8, I would like to filter emails that in the header from field comes with something like this:

```
=?UTF-8?Q?**FirstName**=C2=A0**LastName**?=
```

I want to be able to check first name and last name whether is in upper case, lower case, capitalized, etc.

I currently have a regex like this one `\bFirstName+([ ])+LastName\b` and that works like a charm, but when the header has UTF-8 Encoding does not work.

Comment: How come it works if there are no spaces between `FirstName` and `LastName`?

Comment: What language do you use to perform the Regex search? Also, can you please explain the desired outcome of the regex matches? It seems that your expression only captures spaces as of now

Comment: language-agnostic, it is for a web application for Email Security that allows the use of Regular Expressions, the outcome is to check UTF-8 string of characters on the header of an email address (From:)
Like right now i have this regex working like 55% so far (I am working building the regex on regex101 web page): (?:(\?=)|)(?:(?:( |\n|\r\n)|)(?:( |\t)|)|)(?: |)(=)(?:[A-Za-z0-9].*|)(\?(UTF|utf)\-8\?)([A-Za-z0-9]\?)(FirstName|firstname|FIRSTNAME) ||| so far is  finding this: =?UTF-8?Q?FirstName

Answer (score 3):

This isn't "UTF-8 encoding", it's MIME header encoding (using Quoted-Printable). There's only one reasonable way to deal with it: *decode it* (using an appropriate library for your language, probably found in an email-related package), and run your regex on the decoded result. Trying to match without decoding first, while not actually *impossible*, will be stupidly complex and error-prone.

Comment: Thank you, I agree, I just learned that the code that I am seeing on the email header from the vendor's website, does not match the actual email it seems that they are showing me a translation of the actual code. I am dropping this one, i do not have access to make the conversion on a third party (the vendor) code.

Comment: Also, I am fixing the original regex not to only check for Spaces only, now with the new regex I check Capitalization: \b(JOHN|John|john)+([ ])+(DOE|Doe|doe)\b @Wiktor S.